# Is there anyway to check shipping address country matches with billing address?

Tags: checkout, customer-account, shipping-address, customer-address, billing-address

I have created an account and added a billing address in my account section.
After selecting products, I get to the first /checkout page. I want to do a check does billing address country matches with shipping address country

Is this possible, please can anyone tell me which files I should take a look at?

I am not sure if this is correct (before plugin was what I was thinking)